# Joining contacts and photo tables in Android

Tags: android, contacts, photo

I am developing a phonebook app. I am trying to retrieve contact picture. At first I retrieved all the contacts and then took each contact_id and did a query on the photo table to get the picture. However, it is taking forever to query all the contacts for pics. As in my emulator there are more than 1000 contacts, so, more than 1000 hits on the photo table is being fired. So, is there a way to join the two tables and get the data in a single query?

Below is my code to do it. But I know its wrong. Just gave it a shot. Please someone correct it.

---

```
    String[] projection = new String[]{Contacts._ID, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME};
    String joinCondition = "ContactsContract.Contacts._ID=ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID";
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri contactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    Uri fillUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
    Cursor cur = cr.query(contactUri, projection,
            joinCondition, null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
```

---

Thx!
Rahul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following:

```
    public final String[] columns = {ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, 
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,     
                                    ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI};

   Cursor c = contentResolver.query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, columns, where, args, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

this should return you a cursor with all contacts and their pictures

Comment: If I am not wrong, I will have to do a query to photo table using the photo uri from the results. Again where I started.

Comment: Once you have a thumbnail URI, you just need to set your image view to display the thumbnail. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: I agree I will get the thumbnail uri. But again I will have to go and query or use openContactPhotoInputStream() to get the actual blob. This is working but is taking hell of a long time as there are more than 1000 queries to fire. Is there a way to retrieve all the photos at once?

Answer (score 2):

You should be retrieving the photo thumbnail in the list adapter's getView method. This is already optimized so that you only have to process the records which need to be shown on the screen. So at most you'll have to query a handful at a time, even if you have thousands of contacts.